# UITableView sections issue with different cell colors

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm a newbie to iPhone development. I have a table view with multiple sections in it. I'm changing the color of cells like this and it works fine.

```
if ([indexpath row]%2)
{
    trackCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
else
{
    trackCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:212/255.0 green:212/255.0 blue:212/255.0 alpha:0.1];
}
```

But now the last cell from one section has the same color as the first cell in the next section. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you paste all your UITableView delegate method here?

Comment: The count of row in section begin from 0 again pls paste code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that if cell is in section 1 (or 2, 3, ...)
and the previous section has an odd number of cells, it ends with the same color of the last cell of previous cell.

so, you need to check the previous section number of cells, and if that number is odd, invert your "if" statement, and leave it as it is now if it is even

**EDIT:**

```
int toBeAdded = 0;
if (indexPath.section>0) {
    toBeAdded = ([self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(indexPath.section -1)]) %2 ;
}

if (([indexpath row]+toBeAdded)%2) {
    trackCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
} else {
    trackCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:212/255.0 green:212/255.0 blue:212/255.0 alpha:0.1];
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

seeing "Will Jenkins"... he's right... you need to see all previous sections, not just the previous one...

his way to count all cells in a section is not so good and fast as mine, but his answer is the right one, +1 for him... anyway, the best way could be to combine his loop and my call to tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: Impressed... We were on d same way , I was just late a minute. +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty dirty, but you could count up all the cells before your current one and then use that count to work out the required color. This is untested, but something like the following should do it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int cellCount = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<indexPath.section-1;i++)
    {
        cellCount+=[self numberOfRowsInSection:i]
    }

   cellCount+=indexPath.row;

   if(cellCount%2==0)
   {
    //set one color
   }
   else
   {
    //set other color 
   }
   // blah
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regaridng section change color, need to write your own logic like,

Need to use Static int value irrespective of sections and use already using code with replacing
indexpath.row with your value. i.e.

Static int Index;

```
  if ( Index % 2)
   {
     trackCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   } else  {
trackCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:212/255.0 green:212/255.0 blue:212/255.0 alpha:0.1];
   }
 Index++;
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to your **Number of Rows** in each section...

Suppose you are trying to provide **RED color** to **Odd Rows** and **GREEN color** to **Even Rows** and you have 3 rows in First Section then last cell will have RED color and First cell of Second Section also has RED color.

So you just need to check the **number of rows in Previous Section**. If it is **Even Number** then you should **Maintain the Order of Color** , otherwise simplly **Change the Order of Color** for the Section.